# Android xml animation

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm trying to create an animation and I **can't** use any code for it.
**For what?**
Its for a widget, that means that I can set visibility for views but not animate them.

So this is what I have and I can't figure out why I get blank instead of a animation with a bitmap:

```
<scale
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="800"
    android:fromXScale="1"
    android:fromYScale="1"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="1.2"
    android:toYScale="1.2"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:repeatMode="reverse">

<bitmap android:src="@drawable/icon_enc" ></bitmap>
</scale>
```

so I want to have a ImageView with this as background. 
Why I'm getting a black background? (and so is the preview);

Thanks

Comment: where did you see that you can place a bitmap tag inside scale tag?

Comment: I just assumed. guess I can't.

Answer (score 0):

```
I want to have a ImageView with this as background.
```

The problem is that you are trying to use the animation as the background which will never work instead you can set the image background of your ImageView not through xml but through id and animate it using the xml without the bitmap tag in side of it.

**sample:**

```
<scale
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="800"
android:fromXScale="1"
android:fromYScale="1"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:toXScale="1.2"
android:toYScale="1.2"
android:repeatCount="infinite"
android:repeatMode="reverse">

</scale>
```

And you need to create an instance of ImageVoew in your activity and use the above xml to animate the ImageView programatically.

Here is some [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/06/android-working-with-xml-animations/) to help you.

Comment: Cant do what you said. Its for a widget.

Comment: @Fashizelif it is a widget then you cant animate it, unless you are making your own home screen app.